# What are the ways by which one can debug a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

**Error Example:**

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library     ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building Builder(dirty):
type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I need to see where or which variable is causing this.

Do we have to use breakpoint(s) while debugging a Flutter app or is there something more to it?

I really truly appreciate your input. May I just say that the responses below to this question were perfect. However, there is no code to paste. I had so many bugs. It was just a 1 off question wondering at how one could see the runtime value of variables.

Your response is of huge benefit. Thank you all very much

By the way, the fix to this particular problem can be solved in many ways. 
It happens when trying to do:

```
Text(myDoubleValue.toString());
```

The way you could fix this is by doing

```
var myTempValue = myList[counter]['doubleValue'];
```

(for what its worth) - but the question required more focus on using the debugger than actually solving this 1 issue.

Comment: You have to paste your code. Without it nobody can help you

Comment: I can't believe I got -2 points for knowing how this compiler works

Comment: I think it because your question is quite unclear. You'd better to read this - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. And regarding your question - cause of exception is quite clear but without your code it's impossible to say what is wrong

Comment: @Kiro777 Please add the dart code in your question's description. I am sure that someone from the Flutter community will surely help you then.

Comment: my friends, I just wished to know how the compiler works.. is there no feature that allows you to simply view what the value of each variable is at run time??

Comment: You can add breakpoints in your code which let you know about the value of variable where you have put breakpoints. Run your code in debug mode and see how single step execution of your code. You can find debug option in Run->debug 'main.dart'.

Comment: And the error which you are getting is due to data type specification . You have define some int value to string .

Comment: I have added an answer formatted as per SO's guidelines.

Comment: Hello - Thank you for your guidance. I'm still learning the ropes.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Unfortunately (or fortunately - depending on how you see things) have fixed all my bugs. No more bugs. So right now, I can't really paste anything to show as an example. But the idea is this. If I recall with some compilers like Eclipse, or even Visual Studio - there was a way to look at the state of the variables at runtime. Again, I feel bad about the negative votes as you have guided me to my goal, and without your help, I'd be in a worse place. Again, my heartfelt gratitude for your assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DevTools is what your precisely looking for,

> For debugging and profiling apps, DevTools might be the first tool you
> reach for. DevTools runs in a browser and supports a variety of
> features:
>
> • Source-level debugger
>
> •  Widget inspector that displays a visual widget tree, and “widget
> select” mode where you select a widget in the app and it drills down
> to that widget in the tree.
>
> • Memory profiler
>
> • Timeline view that supports tracing, and importing and exporting trace
> information Logging view

Excerpt taken from the official Flutter docs,

To know more about DevTools head over to the link given below,

https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/debugging

[image: A GIF taken from the above link]

Comment: Thank you so much. Indeed, I tried this, but I could not see any variables and their values being accessed. Perhaps I need to re-examine.

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about how to debug your code - then:

1. you can add breakpoints by clicking on the right from string numbers (red circles on screenshot)
2. after this you can run debug from menu or by clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>

Hope this is what you asked for

[image]

Answer (score 3):

How to find where or which variable is causing this ? Two ways bellow:

1. Normally after crash, the `first link` in `call stack` take you to the code line which cause the crash.

[image]

2. If you enable `All Exceptions` in `BREAKPOINTS` of `Debug Panel`, you should see the line of crashing immediately when you debug.

[image]

### Dev Tool

Or you can use `Dev Tool` as third comment mentioned by @SonofStackoverflow bellow.

Comment: Thank you so much Jerry.. you are enticing me to use Visual Studio Code.. I'm using Android Studio actually. But yes, Im looking for the same functionality in Android Studio. Thank you

Comment: Ah, maybe you better to include `Android Studio` tag in your question ~ ^_^ @Kiro777

Comment: Thank you @SonofStackoverflow for supplement

Comment: No probs...Ultimately we all are the members of one community contributing to SO's QnA DB :)